# Python global variables

Tags: python, global, optional-parameters

I'm new to learning python, and this has been troubling me for a while, any help would be much appreciated! I would like it to create a list of increasing numbers. (I know an easier way of doing this, but this is a simplified example of the problem in another code where I can't use any simpler method.)

The code;

```
increase = 0

def adder(number):

    number+=1
    return number

while True:
    adder(increase)
    print(increase)
```

Comment: Why not use a list comprehension or `for` loop?

Comment: I want the value of the parameter to change, allowing the new value to be called again in the function later. Would reassigning to the global help with that? If so, how would I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the returned value.

```
increase = adder(increase)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
number += 1
```

you are re-assigning `number` rather than modifying it's existing value.  it's as if you did

```
number = number + 1
```

If you want to modify the global, you will need to store it back in when calling the function

```
increase = adder(increase)
```

at this point you can also simplify the adder function a bit

```
def adder(number):
    return number + 1
```

If, however, you want a function to modify a global like that, it will have to do so explicitly.  But if this is what you want you should rethink your program:

```
increase = 0

def adder():
    global increase
    increase += 1

while True:
    adder()
    print(increase)
```

Comment: If you _want_ a function to modify a global like that, but you probably shouldn't want this.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist agreed.